# How to put the a string into a text file in PHP?

Tags: php, file-io

How do I put a string into a txt file in php?

I want to write string like this:

```
        1,hello,world!
        2,welcome
```

Then have those two lines be in the file.

Comment: i only want to output the result in list style.

Comment: what is "list"? HTML list? You have to be more certain in your expressions. Nobody can read your mind. If you want to add `<li>` tags to your output- just add it.

Comment: why do you want to store numbers with these lines? why not to store only lines?

Comment: are you going to add lines consequently or all at once?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To write to a txt file:

```
<?php
$file = 'file.txt';
$data = 'this is your string to write';
file_put_contents($file, $data);
?>
```

To echo contents of that file somewhere on a page (remember the page must have a .php extension for php to work):

```
<?php
// place this piece of code wherever you want the file contents to appear
readfile('file.txt');
?>
```

EDIT:

To answer your another question from the comments:

When saving your data to the file, the original code is OK, just use that.
The different code comes when echoing the contents from the file, so now it will look like this:

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$contents = explode("\n", $contents);
foreach($contents as $line){
   $firstComma = (strpos($line, ","))+1;
   $newLine = substr($line, $firstComma);
   echo $newLine."\n"; 
}
?>
```

Try it like that. I don't have my server here, so I cannot test it, but I believe I didn't make any mistake there.

Comment: I consider readfile being more safe than include. just in case

Comment: but if i want to wite the string like this(on the above) than output in list style. how shoud i do?

Comment: it is usually unnecessary to use a loop for such output

Comment: Instead of exploding on "\n" (and all that string manipulation in the loop), why not just use the [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function? The format the op is storing the data is just a csv file: $fileHandle = fopen('file.txt', 'r'); while($row = fgetcsv($fileHandle)) { echo $row[1].PHP_EOL; } (obviously add error handling to this)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a string to a file with `file_put_contents`. Not sure what you mean by output to HTML. 
 Do you just want echo?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Mysterion given the simplicity of the OP's question I personally feel that this answer does answer the question since it identifies 'file_put_contents' as a means to write to a file. Admittedly its not a very detailed answer but it is sufficient in that no further info could really be given within expansion by the OP.