# Permanently save data in a file on a website and edit it

Tags: php, html, web

How to save a data on a HTML website to be saved permanently (when I close the explorer, the data stays there forever until editing).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440912/how-to-put-the-a-string-into-a-txt-file-in-php  - Is this could helps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need database to do that job, it must be some-kind of setting in which once page is loading should fetch to db that setting and then display it, Also you have to give user the opportunity to change that setting

```
<?php //connect to db
 //run your query, lets say the variable hold values from DB is $content
?>
.....
.....
<body>
<div>
 <?php echo $content; ?>
</div>

.....
.....
```

Comment: there is no way then, and in case of his problem nothing state about loading or reloading the page, he can use even Ajax  to do so, but at the end of the day DB must be there @Mawg

Comment: That's so helpful fas M. Thanks .. I will try it